Do I need to notify the airlines that I now have Global Entry?
Do I need to notify the airlines that I now have Global Entry? I purchased my tickets before I got Global Entry.

Did you already have TSA Pre? If not you should add that.

You can always add your Global Entry number or  KTN (Known Traveler Number) when you you check in for your flight. Technically it's not required but it's good practice and it will get you TSAPre privileges which can be quite helpful if you have a connecting flight after your arrival in the US.

In my experience some airlines allow you to enter the KTN once and for all in their online FF system, others don't (I won't mention names) and if so you should give the number at checkin, it will show up on our boarding pass and you can go thorough a shorter security line (the TSApre line or equivalent). I have the 9-digit KTN written down in my wallet for this reason.

Minor clarification: assuming OP is currently in the US, it would also be helpful even without a connecting flight because they'll have access to PreCheck on departure.
